# Nginx as a forward proxy

Tags: nginx, directive, resolve

I am trying to configure nginx as a forward proxy and establish persistent connection between the nginx and the upstream server. When I set

```
server {
     location / {
     proxy_pass http://$http_host$request_uri;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Connection "";
     ...
    }
}
```

in the location context, it has no effect until I have a upstream module that has `keepalive` directive in it. Is it mandatory to specify the upstream module with keepalive directive?
If I do that way,

```
http
{
    upstream up {
      server $http_host;
      keepalive 20;
    }
    server {
      proxy_pass http://up$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I get the error host not found in upstream "$http_host". Looks like the server directive is not using it as variable but merely looking for a server named $http_host? I tried finding hints in online resources but couldn't get help. I need someone to point me how this goes wrong?